# Can you assert an object property based on the property of another individual using the OWL 2 Functional-Style syntax?

Tags: owl, protege

Let's say we have the following declarations:

```
Declaration(ObjectProperty(:likes))

Declaration( NamedIndividual(:John))
Declaration( NamedIndividual(:George) )
Declaration( NamedIndividual(:Fishing))
```

And the following assertion:

```
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:likes :John :Fishing)
```

Is there a way to assert that George doesn't like whatever John likes?

I thought of the following:

```
NegativeObjectPropertyAssertion(
  :likes
  :George
  ObjectHasValue(
     ObjectInverseOf(:likes)
     :John
  )
)
```

But I cannot load the above ontology in Protege so I assume the syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectPropertyAssertions (respectively NegativeObjectPropertyAssertions) can only make assertions about the existence (respectively none existence) of relations between 2 individuals. What you are trying to do is define a relation between an individual and a class using property assertions. This is not possible.

However, you can define the class of things that `john` likes as follows:

```
EquivalentClasses(JohnLikes ObjectSomeValuesFrom(ObjectInverseOf(likes>) ObjectOneOf(john)))
```

Note that if you want the activities that is liked by `john` to be listed, you have to give a name to the class `ObjectSomeValuesFrom(ObjectInverseOf(likes>) ObjectOneOf(john))` - in this case `JohnLikes`. This is because the reasoner only gives inferences for named classes not anonymous classes.

Then the activities that `george` likes will be those that `john` does not like (i.e. `not JohnLikes`).

Here is an example ontology that defines some known activities as well as activities liked and not liked by `john`:

```
Ontology(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178>

Declaration(Class(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#GeorgeLikes>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#JohnLikes>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Person>))
Declaration(ObjectProperty(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#likes>))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess>))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing>))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#george>))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking>))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john>))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading>))

############################
#   Classes
############################

# Class: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity>)

EquivalentClasses(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> ObjectOneOf(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading>))
DisjointClasses(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Person>)

# Class: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#GeorgeLikes> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#GeorgeLikes>)

EquivalentClasses(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#GeorgeLikes> ObjectComplementOf(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#JohnLikes>))

# Class: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#JohnLikes> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#JohnLikes>)

EquivalentClasses(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#JohnLikes> ObjectSomeValuesFrom(ObjectInverseOf(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#likes>) ObjectOneOf(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john>)))


############################
#   Named Individuals
############################

# Individual: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess>)

ClassAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess>)

# Individual: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing>)

ClassAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing>)

# Individual: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#george> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#george>)

ClassAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Person> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#george>)

# Individual: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking>)

ClassAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking>)

# Individual: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john>)

ClassAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Person> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john>)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#likes> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess>)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#likes> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading>)
NegativeObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#likes> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing>)
NegativeObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#likes> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking>)

# Individual: <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading>)

ClassAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#Activity> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading>)


DifferentIndividuals(<http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#chess> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#fishing> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#george> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#hiking> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#john> <http://www.semanticweb.org/SO77732178#reading>)
)
```